# Multicast name resolution in the latest Win10

Tags: resolution, windows-10-upgrade, multicast, nslookup, zeroconf

Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.590)

I haven't found any working solution for the multicast name resolution issue in Win10. I cannot imagine, that everybody started to set-up an own Domain Name Server for his home-office environment, so I haven't given the hope yet, that there might be a solution out there...

My trials so far:

- Turning on some relevant services: https://mspoweruser.com/microsoft-shares-a-fix-for-network-problems-on-windows-10-april/
- Installing iTunes for Bonjour Service (I cannot actually find the service any more)
- Ensuring in the Local Group Policy (gpedit.msc) that Multicast Name Resolution is turned on
- Ensuring firewall rules (opening ports) are enabled ("File and Printer Sharing (LLMNR-UDP-In"), "Network Discovery ("LLMNR-UDP-In"))

Any hints are welcome except of those pointing to security concerns of a multicast name resolution (I won't poison my own subnet, promise!).

Comment: What issue exactly? And which protocol are you trying to use – mDNS or LLMNR?

Comment: I try to ping mymachine.local and mymachine, the name resolution already fails. My machines on the network can only be accessed by IP addresses.